# How can i relate some tables that have composite keys as primary?

Tags: database, database-design, uml

I have a table called product which has {P_name,P_quantity,...}
and a table which called sub that have{category_name,sub_category_name} one category has many sub_category and table specs which has name and value for example size 4 cm how can i relate those tables to gather on Chen's diagram.

i tried to join specs with product as many to one and then make product id and sub_category as a composite key but i do not know how to make that on Chen diagram and also is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?!
[image]
and let me note that, this is very bad practice about the naming the columns as `p_name`, `p_quantity`. there is no need for `p_`